# Insulators (also called Dielectrics) which cannot conduct Electricity

Tags: particle-physics, electrostatics

How Dielectrics as an Insulating materials transmit electric effect without Conducting Electricity ? How its Possible ??

Answer (score 1):

Electrical conduction is charge carriers (most often electrons) moving through a conductor. In an insulator there are no free charge carriers to allow conduction. However electric field effects can still propagate as the material is made up of atoms, consisting of positive protons and negative electrons. In the simplest case these will act as a dipole. These charges can be effected by an E-field, while no conduction can occur.

Answer (score 0):

Dielectric have bonded charges. thoses bonded charge oscillate when an electric field is applied. And thoses oscillations can propagate the electric field thought the dielectric media

Comment: but why we don't get shock like effect when electric current is passing through insulator like rubber slipper which we have wear in our foot?

Comment: I think you're confusing electric field and electric current. In insulator, there is no electric current. So, you can't get a electric shock or something like that.

Answer (score -3):

Displacement current - D. Have another look at Maxwell's equations.

Comment: Even though displacement current is a key word for the correct answer it would be better is you would also explain why, since the question is "how" an electric field in transmitted by an dielectric.